# nyroModal AJAX and Wordpress Data

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery, nyromodal

I'm currently using nyroModal to pull a HTML form page. This form's values are automatically pre filled with the current user's data when the user is logged in, as well as information from the current page. I'm using the typical nyroModal call script so

```
  $('#get_deal, #contact_first').nyroModal();
```

The form loads just fine when I have just the form with no Wordpress functions, however when I call the Wordpress function get_currentuserinfo(); it errors out and gives me the error call to undefined function. When I go to the particular page it is showing the data being pulled correctly.

I figure it has to do with it being AJAX, but not sure how to correct it. Should I be loading a separate script once the nyroModal has finished loading? If so any tips on how to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Adam

Comment: Was able to fix this myself. Can't believe I didn't think of this, I just called directly to the Wordpress page instead of the php file and it fixed the issue.